# How to check if my PCAP file contain Bad CheckSum using PcapDotNet

Tags: c#, packet, pcap, pcap.net

Is it possible to check if my PCAP file contain Bad CheckSum using `PcapDotNet` ?
Of course i want to check `IP`, `TCP` and `UDP` layers.
Currently i only can check if the packet is valid (the packet valid unless an invalid part was found: bad checksum, illegal field value, packet too short...)
Also i can get the `Checksum` value (ushort value):

```
Packet packet;
ushort ipChecksum = packet.Ethernet.IpV4.HeaderChecksum;
ushort tcpChecksum = packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.Checksum;
ushort udpChecksum = packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Udp.Checksum;
```

is it possible to verify it's valid value ?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting https://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/discussions/576637:

IpV4Datagram has IsHeaderChecksumCorrect property.

IpDatagram (base class for IpV4Datagram and IpV6Datagram) has IsTransportChecksumCorrect, which checks either UDP or TCP checksums.